# Why would /usr/bin/rfcomm (Linux utility) fail, but C function succeed?

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I have a C program that successfully established an rfcomm connection with a bluetooth device.

```
void doConnect( char const* btaddr )
{
   int sock = socket( AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM );

   bdaddr_t ba;
   struct sockaddr_rc addr;
   str2ba( btaddr, &ba );
   memset( &addr, 0, sizeof(addr) );
   addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
   memcpy( &(addr.rc_bdaddr), &ba, sizeof(ba) );
   addr.rc_channel = 1;
   int result = connect( sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr ) );   
   ...
}
```

However, when I run the the rfcomm utility application (http://linux.die.net/man/1/rfcomm), as:

```
/usr/bin/rfcomm connect bt_addr
```

I get the error:

```
"Can't find a config entry for rfcomm0"
```

With the command:

```
rfcomm connect bt_addr
```

I get the error:

```
"Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Host is down"
```

So, how does rfcomm connect differ from my C program and why can't it make the connection? Am I using the utility incorrectly?

== edit ==

Results of strace from my C program:

```
socket(PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, 3)    = 3
...
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_BLUETOOTH, sa_data=">\16\303O!\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 10) = 0
```

Results of strace from /usr/bin/rfcomm program:

```
socket(PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_RAW, 3)       = 3
socket(PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, 3)    = 4
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_BLUETOOTH, sa_data="\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 10) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_BLUETOOTH, sa_data="\0\0\0\0\0\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 10) = -1 EHOSTDOWN (Host is down)
```

Comment: Compare the output of `strace rfcomm connect ...` and `strace your_program`.

Comment: By the way, when you put spaces on the inside of your parentheses you make the baby Jesus cry.

Comment: Bluetooth stacks make babies cry. I've add the strace info (nice utility BTW!). It looks like rfcomm calls bind before connect. Why does it do that and how do I make it stop?

Comment: More importantly, from your output, rfcomm calls bind with a zero address. At least in AF_INET, AF_INET6 and AF_LOCAL, a zero socket address equals the wildcard * : * (i.e. let kernel choose randomly for each * part), but the wildcard is the  default _anyhow_. It would be rather weird if AF_BLUETOOTH did not exert the same behavior. What if you add binding to zero to your program, does it fail as well?

Comment: Note that rfcomm connects to a different address than your own program (cf. `sa_data` in your strace outputs).